# Dispatcher.Invoke parameter throws IlegalOperationException

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, asynchronous

I have following code where I am getting `IlegalOperationException` because my parameter owns another thread. I know why I am getting this exception but I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
//called on UI thread
public void redraw()
{
     new Thread(setPoints).Start(); //calculating new points
}

void setPoints()
{
    PointCollection c = new PointCollection();
    //calculating points to collection
    Task.Factory.StartNew((Action<object>)((p) => { polyline.Points = (PointCollection)p; }), c);

}
```

EDIT:

Ok here is line with dispatcher

```
polyline.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action<PointCollection>)((p) => { polyline.Points = p; }), c);
```

Comment: I don't see any `Dispatcher.Invoke()` in your code.

Comment: Oh sorry it's old code. I'm solving this for 2 hours so I'm a little angry. It's my fault. But problem is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess  you need to do something like this

```
private void reDraw()
        {
             Task<IList<Point>> calculatePointTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //Use the list of points instead of thread-bound PointCollection
                IList<Point> pointCollection = new List<Point>();

                //Simulating that we calculate points
                Thread.Sleep(3000);

                pointCollection.Add(new Point(10,20));
                pointCollection.Add(new Point(10,20));

                return pointCollection;
            });

        calculatePointTask.ContinueWith(ante =>
            {


                var calculatedPoints = calculatePointTask.Result;

                Action<IList<Point>> updateUI = (points) =>
                    {

                        var pointCollection = new PointCollection(points);
                        polyline.Points = pointCollection;

                    };

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(updateUI, calculatedPoints);



            }, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        }
```

in your redraw function.

EDIT: use a list of points instead of a PointCollection instance when calculating points

Comment: This throws: (InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.) Somewhere on UI thread: 
from log:
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()

Comment: Or if there is another way to async calculate points and then set them to polyline it will be perfect, but i don't know about another better way to do this.

Comment: Yes this works perfectly. Thanks a lot. It's little complicated but it works and that's main.

Answer (score 2):

PointCollection is a DependencyObject, you cannot instantiate that from one thread and access it from other. Try doing your calculations in a separate thread to generate whatever data you need, and then instantiate the PointCollection in the UI Thread.

Comment: But when i make PointCollection in UI thread i can't add points to it in another thread. Or how you mean it.

Comment: You'd add the new points with the dispatcher if you are doing work on a background thread.

Comment: Agree with @MetroSmurf, generate whatever double values  you need for the points in the other thread, but create the point objects themselves in the UI thread

Comment: Yes this will work i think. But calculate value on background thread and then call UI thread for very point will be slower then do all on UI thread and application will freez for calculating time. There isn't smarter solution?